Getting wrong pointer addresses when accessing struct members by offset
I'm currently reversing some firmware und need to write patches in C. This is a very simple code to illustrate my problem:
#include <iostream>

struct inner {
    int32_t a;
    int16_t b;
};

struct test {
    int32_t one;
    int32_t two;
    char* data;
};

int main()
{
    struct inner inner;
    inner.a = 4;
    inner.b = 5;
    
    struct test test;
    test.data = (char*)(&inner);
    
    char *ptr = (char*)(&test);
    
    int off = offsetof(struct test,data);
    
    std::cout << "Data offset: " << off;
    std::cout << "\n" << (&inner);
    
    char* in = (char*)(ptr+off);
    
    std::cout << "\n" << (void*)in;

    return 0;
}

This code actually prints two pointer addresses, the second one being exactly 0x10 higher than the first one. This obviously also results into not being able to access the members a and b of the inner struct using this way.
I basically tried to change the pointer types, but didn't manage to find any correct solution by trying. In my understanding, casting to char* should allow me to access members by byte offset. I know that some cast are not needed, I did however get always the same results no matter what I do.
EDIT: This solved my problem:
#include <iostream>

struct inner {
    int32_t a;
    int16_t b;
};

struct test {
    int32_t one;
    int32_t two;
    char* data;
};

int main()
{
    struct inner inner;
    inner.a = 4;
    inner.b = 5;
    
    struct test test;
    test.data = (char*)(&inner);
    
    char *ptr = (char*)(&test);
    
    int off = offsetof(struct test,data);
    
    std::cout << "Data offset: " << off;
    std::cout << "\n" << (void*)test.data;
    
    char* in = *((char**)(ptr+off));
    
    std::cout << "\n" << (void*)in;
    
    int32_t a = (int32_t)(*in);
    int16_t b = (int16_t)(*(in+0x4));
    
    std::cout << "\nA: " << a << " B: " << b;

    return 0;
}


I'm not sure I get what you are trying to do, but you cannot access members of one object through pointer to another object without invoking Undefined Behaviour.

You are printing addresses of two completely unrelated objects, inner and test.data. You cannot access either one with the other one.

Guys, he's talking about some firmware. It doesn't matter whether his code runs on some obscure platform that nobody has ever heard about, and pointer arithmetic is pretty predictable if you're not glued to your standards book.

@ChristianStieber I've been writing firmwares and we never allowed ourselves for UB (consciously). If OP wants to rely on implementation-specific behaviour, they should mention in question compiler and platform they are targetting, otherwise the question is unanswerable. Though it's still unclear to me what they are trying to do, UB or not.

Your problem, from what I can tell, is that you're looking at &inner and another pointer that's baslcally &test + something. There is no need for the storage locations of inner and test to have any predictable relation to each other. When I run this, for example, the second output is actually 4 bytes BELOW the first one (so, in terms of memory layout, the compiler placed test before inner, not after it).

@ChristianStieber pointer arithmetic is pretty predictable if, for example, you know how the value of a pointer is different from the address of a pointer. If you mix these things together, it's going to be pretty chaotic.

Your 0x10(aka 16) offset is easy to explain: if the compiler placed inner before test in memory, we have a 6 bytes inner followed by a 2 byte gap, followed by the first two members of test which are also 8 bytes, so the datapointer is stored at a 16 byte offset relative to inner. However, that's very unpredictable -- I wouldn't rely on that, even with my easy-going attitude towards "use platform dependencies if needed".

Sadly, it is pretty hard to explain. I'm currently working on a firmware of a WiFi chip for my master thesis with a custom framework which lets me write patches in C for it (pretty hacky and sometimes unstable). The framework should be sure, that structs are predictable (all data is behind each other without any padding). I have a frame buffer struct, that contains a member char* data. This is the payload of a frame. This data member is cast to several structs (headers for protocols) and then accessed. Because I can't easily define that many structs, I tried to access member by offsets.

Don't write the solution into the answer; self-answer the question instead. Also, don't throw a block of code at the readers; do explain what the difference is and why it solves the problem you had.

You want to print the value of test.data, not its address.
 char** in = (char**)(ptr+off);
 //  ^^           ^^

 std::cout << "\n" << (void*)*in;
 //                          ^


oh thank you. You managed to get my brain unwrapped. With you hint I managed to get this work. Thank you! A added a solution that works for me to my initial post.
